# SQL split volume into buckets with no repetition of bucket ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Im solving maybe simple but for me impossible task in MS SQL. I have 2 tables- 1 with company name and total volume of used bottles. In second table I have a list of buckets with unique ID and their bottle capacity. My task is to assign to each company correct number of buckets (to cover all volume of bottles) while not using the same buckets twice (not repeat buckets with the same ID for 2 or moře companies).
Is anyone able to help me with that?
Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are the bottles always the same size?

Comment: Yes, they are the same size. Even the buckets capacity is the same (20 bottles).

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional simplifications that every bottle is the same and every bucket has the same capacity (per your comment), this will do the trick:

```
-- demo schema
create table companies (cname char, bottlesUsed int);
create table buckets (id int, capacity int);

-- demo data
insert companies values ('a', 41), ('b', 2), ('c', 5), ('d', 50);
insert buckets select top 20 row_number() over (order by object_id), 20 from sys.objects;

with 
   bucketnums as 
   (
      select i = row_number() over (order by id),
             id
      from   buckets
   ),
   bucketRanges as
   (
      select   cname,
               firstBucketNum = 1 + lag(lastBucketNum, 1, 0) over (order by cname),
               lastBucketNum               
      from     (  -- running total of bucket count required by each customer
                  select cname,
                         lastBucketNum = sum(ceiling(bottlesUsed * 1.0 / 20)) 
                           over (order by cname rows unbounded preceding)
                  from   companies
               )  t
   )
   
select   conmpanyName = br.cname,
         allocatedBucketId = bn.id
from     bucketRanges     br
join     bucketnums       bn on bn.i between firstBucketNum and lastBucketNum;
```

If the bottle size or bucket capacity is variable, this problem becomes *much* more... "interesting" :)